# How to move attributes between hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have

```
hash1 = {:sym1 => "aaa", :sym2 => "bbb"}
hash2 = {:sym20 => "ccc", :sym21 => "ddd"}
```

how to make

```
hash1 = {:sym1 => "aaa"}
hash2 = {:sym2 => "bbb", :sym20 => "ccc", :sym21 => "ddd"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hash2[:sym2] = hash1.delete(:sym2)
```

Comment: Or use hash2.merge! sym2: hash1.delete(:sym2)